# Modular properties of weight $\frac{3}{2}$ theta functions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

Define the theta-functions $g(z) = - \sum_{n \in \mathbf{Z}} \left(n + \frac{1}{6} \right) e^{3 \pi i \left( n + \frac{1}{6} \right)^2 z}$. How can I show that $$g(z + 1) = e^{\frac{1}{24}2 \pi i} g(z)$$ and $$g\left(-\frac{1}{z} \right) = - (-i z)^{\frac{3}{2}} \sum_{n \in \mathbf{Z}} (-1)^n \left(n + \frac{1}{3} \right) e^{3 \pi i \left( n + \frac{1}{3} \right)^2 z}$$
This example is from S. Zweger's paper "Mock Theta Functions and Real Analytic Modular Forms", where he states that this can be shown "using standard-methods". I don't know those standard-methods, so I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is very late, but I stumbled across this while looking for something else.

Let $a(n) := -(n+1/6)$ for ease of notation.

For the first identity, we have
\begin{align*}
g(z+1) &= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a(n)e^{3\pi i( n + 1/6)^{2}z}e^{3\pi i(n + 1/6)^{2}} \\
&= \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}a(n)e^{3\pi i(n + 1/6)^{2}z}e^{3\pi i\left( \frac{6n+1}{6} \right)^{2}}\\
&= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a(n)e^{3\pi i(n + 1/6)^{2}z}e^{2\pi i(6n+1)^{2}/24}\\
&= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a(n)e^{3\pi i(n + 1/6)^{2}z}e^{3\pi in^{2}}e^{\pi i}e^{2\pi i/24}\\
&= e^{2\pi i/24}g(z).
\end{align*}

For the second part, use [Poisson summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that due to $\sum_n n e^{2i\pi n^2 z}=0$ the function is mostly $\sum_n (\frac{n}6)n e^{2i\pi n^2 z}$  (with $(\frac{n}6) I mean the quadratic character $\bmod 6$, which is non-primitive)